# about Python text replace

Tags: python, text, replace

I have a text file

```
#8,09-24,17:043.00,3.30,2.03,#7,09-24,16:222.95,3.30,2.05,#6,09-24,15:58,3.00,3.30,2.03
```

I would like to change it to

```
#8,09-24,17:04,3.00,3.30,2.03,#7,09-24,16:22,2.95,3.30,2.05,#6,09-24,15:58,3.00,3.30,2.03
```

What I can think of is to use the replace

```
textfile=textfile.replace(":01,",":01").replace(":02,",":02") #etc
textfile=textfile.replace(":01",":01,").replace(":02",":02,") #etc
```

May I know what other method can do the same things without typing all the possible result out.
Thank you

Comment: What changes, can you please tell?

Comment: the changes will be on time
some are ":00," some are ":00" I would like to change it all to ":00,"

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need to replace the `17:043.00`-like values to `17:04,3.00` (likely yto fix some kind of csv file).

You could use a regex and `re.sub`:

```
import re

text = '#8,09-24,17:043.00,3.30,2.03,#7,09-24,16:222.95,3.30,2.05,#6,09-24,15:58,3.00,3.30,2.03'
text2 = re.sub(r'(\d\d:\d\d)(\d+)', r'\1,\2', text)
```

output:

```
#8,09-24,17:04,3.00,3.30,2.03,#7,09-24,16:22,2.95,3.30,2.05,#6,09-24,15:58,3.00,3.30,2.03
```

NB. you can [test how the regex works here](https://regex101.com/r/AIVV2b/2)

Answer (score 0):

Your file appears to contain data in a fixed-width pattern. Assuming that's the case then you could do this:-

```
S = '#8,09-24,17:043.00,3.30,2.03,#7,09-24,16:222.95,3.30,2.05,#6,09-24,15:58,3.00,3.30,2.03'
T = []
for i in range(0, len(S), 29):
    k = i + 14
    T.append(S[i:k]+','+S[k:k+15])
print(''.join(T))
```